# Test Admob url to android market

Tags: android, admob

I just started using Admob to promote my app and noticed that it changes my play.google.com link to a market:// link.

How do I test if the link works?  I don't own an android but have had friends try it and it doesn't seem to work (it takes them to a google search page when they enter the link in their browser).  I know that the play.google.com link works but Admob keeps changing it to market://

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one tactic I use - go to [Generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) and enter the market `URL` as a `URL` barcode. Ask someone with an Android to scan the barcode - if it works, it will take you straight to the app in the store.

Any other method I've tried invokes the browser which doesn't understand the `market:// protocol`

Comment: So if someone doesn't have the Google Play market and they click on the ad, they won't see my app description?